# Join к уже отфильтрованной и обработанной таблице Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

интересует решение задачи, а именно, Django по умолчанию использует INNER JOIN для работы с таблицей, у меня вопрос, можно ли как-то самому задать какой будет использоваться JOIN, и к какой таблице, ибо он автоматически это определяет а мне это важно задать JOIN к уже отфильтрованной таблице. Заранее спасибо за уделенное внимание.

```
class Segments(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Сегменты (Segments)'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=32,
                             verbose_name='Название сегмента')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ': ' + str(self.days_difference)


class Client(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Клиенты (Clients)'

    fio = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='ФИО')
    create_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата создания')
    first_source = models.ForeignKey(MarketingSourceList,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     verbose_name='Первый Источник')
    distribution = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Рассылка')
    segment = models.ForeignKey(Segments,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                verbose_name='Сегмент',
                                default=7)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fi


class Orders(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы (Orders)'

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               verbose_name='Клиент')
    source = models.ForeignKey(MarketingSourceList,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               verbose_name='Источник')
    receipts = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Кол-во чеков')
    summa = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Сумма')
    order_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата заказа')
```

Проблема в том, что в таблицу Orders, сыпятся разные заказы, в день может быть по несколько штук, с разными значениями sum, и receipts.

Мне нужно посчитать, сумму сумм, сумму чеков, полученных за сегменты, и при этом, вывести кол-во пользователей в каждом сегменте.

Comment: а какая разница? если таблица отфильтрована и запрос выполнен, то потом будет еще запрос для нового запроса, где будете джойнить таблицы. а если не выполнялся первый запрос знач таблица еще не отфильтрована.

Comment: Факт в том, что мне нужно джойнить с самого начала одну таблицу к уже отфильтрованной, и потом уже с основной таблицей взаимодействовать. Банально мне нужно чтоб INNER JOIN был не к ванильной таблице, а к кастомной, мной созданной

Comment: есть методы `select_related` и `prefetch_related`. первая джойнит связанное по FK а второе можно сортировать через Prefetch объекты. Приложите хотя бы модели. 99% ваша проблема решается через `select_related` и `prefetch_related`.

Comment: Хорошо, минуту, сейчас приложу модели

Comment: Добавил кода и саму цель

Comment: суммы за все сегменты, а клиенты за отдельные сегменты?

Comment: Суммы за 1 сегмент, клиентов за 1 сегмент. То есть есть 2 клиента сигмента 1, мы слаживаем их суммы, и выводим что их 2 , всё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum, Count, Prefetch, F


class Segments(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Сегменты (Segments)'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=32,
                             verbose_name='Название сегмента')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    # Вот нужный вам код
    @classmethod
    def gettest(cls):
        qs = cls.objects.prefetch_related(
            'client_set',
            'client_set__orders_set',
        ).annotate(
            sum_receipts=Sum(F('client__orders__receipts')),
            sum_summa=Sum(F('client__orders__summa')),
            count_clients=Count(F('client')),
        )

        for x in qs:
            print(x, x.sum_receipts, x.sum_summa, x.count_clients)
    # Конец


class Client(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Клиенты (Clients)'

    fio = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='ФИО')
    create_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата создания')
    distribution = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Рассылка')
    segment = models.ForeignKey(Segments,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                verbose_name='Сегмент',
                                default=7)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fio


class Orders(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы (Orders)'

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               verbose_name='Клиент')
    receipts = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Кол-во чеков')
    summa = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Сумма')
    order_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата заказа')


Segments.gettest()
```

Воможно нужно будет поправить опечатки.

Если не будет работать - заменить строки в `Sum` и `Count` на объекты `F()` с этимиже строками как параметры, например `Sum('client_set__orders_set__receipt') => Sum(F('client_set__orders_set__receipt'))`

PS: Надеюсь поможет с первого трая

PPS: Не помогло

Comment: Не сработало, пишет что нет полей client_set и client_set__orders_set

Comment: Тогда, можете указать `related_name` для FK и M2M полей, не помню как они называются по дефолту

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'client_set' into field. Choices are: client, crm, days_difference, id, orders, title, triggersettings

Comment: `client_set` => `client`, `client_set__order....` => `client_orders`

Comment: Пишет что не находит, вот такая ошибка 

{AttributeError}Cannot find 'client' on Segments object, 'client' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Я попробовал со старыми данными, и старые данные не аннотируются но префетч отрабатывает

Comment: обновил. работает у меня на локалке

Comment: Смотрите оно почти правильно работает, оно выдает неверным кол-во клиентов, я уже придумал другой способ и всё-таки решил по старинке через сырые запросы поработать, ибо эта информация только на вывод идет, спасибо вам за желание и возможность помощи, я позже к этому вернусь и проверю и отпишу что не так